# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A + B, AB

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:

Suppose that A is an *m × m* symmetric matrix with eigenvalues λ1, . . . , λm and associated eigenvectors x1, . . . ,xm, whereas B is an *m × m* symmetric matrix with eigenvalues γ1, . . . , γm and associated eigenvectors x1, . . . ,xm;
that is, A and B have common eigenvectors.

a) Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A + B

b) Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of AB

Comment: You might want to use MathJaxx to format your question. However, you should use the fact that both matrices can be simultaneously diagonalized.

Comment: part a) reminds me of part a) of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658767/eigenvector-of-two-matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(A+B\right)x_{i}=Ax_{i}+Bx_{i}=\lambda_{i}x_{i}+\gamma_{i}x_{i}=x_{i}\cdot\left(\lambda_{i}+\gamma_{i}\right)$$
$$AB\left(x_{i}\right)=A\left(\gamma_{i}x_{i}\right)=\gamma_{i}A\left(x_{i}\right)=\gamma_{i}\lambda_{i}x_{i}$$